# Getting started in creating simple bootable C program

Tags: boot

Could someone guide me on what path/steps to take to create a simple bootable hello world program? I have the basic knowledge of C/C++.

My aim is to create a **very simple** OS.

I would like as much relevant links to references and samples as possible.

Comment: Search for the term bootloader. Tons of resources available online. See: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tips/boot-loader.aspx

Comment: I think the big question here would be "on what processor?" In most cases, I'd suggest looking at a bootloader for that processor to get an idea -- and yes, you will be writing some assembler, your basic output routines, etc. if you want the program to truly stand alone.

Comment: Somewhat related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145501/writing-an-operating-system-in-c/2145556#2145556

Comment: No matter how many very's you put in front of it, even a simple OS is going to take time... especially when you want to start talking to the keyboard. :-)

Comment: @Frank Heck, it'd get hard just trying to print something to the screen.  You'd need some sort of display driver/framebuffer driver AFAIK.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See [this.](http://www.osdever.net/tutorials/view/hello-world-boot-loader)  It's a tutorial for a very basic boot loader.  It doesn't have much to do with C/C++, but it has some really good information on the basic building blocks of a bootloader.

If you're really curious about the building blocks, there are more in-depth resources in the form of textbooks.  This tutorial, for instance, doesn't explain why the boot loader must end with `55 AA`.  In addition, it's relatively narrow.

Comment: Thanks for plugging OSdever.net. If anyone has anyone questions try forums.osdever.net. We're pretty good at helping eachother out ;)

Comment: This answer isn't really in the spirit of SO. I'm late, I know.

Answer (score 0):

You want to build a statically linked binary (no ld.so involved), and you start it by jumping to its entry point. The entry point is usually the start of the .text section.  Maye run objdump --section-headers *image* on it to find out its adress.

If you're trying to run on an embedded device, check out how the kernel of an embedded OS is built and booted.  For example, see how U-Boot brings up  an Ångström linux based system.